# Is it possible to merge stderr and stdout in C?

Tags: c, cocoa, stdout, stderr

I need to merge stderr and stdout because I want my debug and the exceptions in the same log file. I tried

```
    NSString *logPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Library/Tag Monster/log.log"];
    freopen([logPath fileSystemRepresentation], "a", stderr);
    freopen([logPath fileSystemRepresentation], "a", stdout);
```

but this messes up the order. It prints the stderr messages at the top of the file.
Or is there a better way to log in cocoa? NSLog just spams the syslog :P

**Edit**: 
Thants my log macro:

```
#ifdef DEBUG_MODE_LEVEL_KEEP
#define DLogK(...) (void)printf("%s: %s\n",  __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, [[NSString    stringWithFormat:__VA_ARGS__] UTF8String])
#else
#define DLogK(...)
#endif
```

If I just redirect stderr to a logfile and log with

```
fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n",  __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, [[NSString    stringWithFormat:__VA_ARGS__] UTF8String])
```

it does not work either. Shouldn't that just work?

Thanks

Comment: The order may be messed up because `stderr` is flushed (i.e. written to file) automatically, while `stdout` is flushed only when explicitly told to (or the internal buffer is full), though in most Unices, `stdout` is also automatically flushed if the output is a terminal.  Does the output get re-ordered if you don't try to log to a file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `dup2()` in `unistd.h`, you could close both `stderr` and `stdout` and re-direct them to a file.  For instance:

```
#include <sys/stat.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <fcntl.h> 

int log_file;
mode_t mode = S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH;

log_file = open("my_log_file.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, mode);

if (dup2(log_file, fileno(stderr)) != fileno(stderr) ||
    dup2(log_file, fileno(stdout)) != fileno(stdout))
{
    perror("Unable to redirect output");
}
```

Now both `stderr` and `stdout`, when used, will write to my_log_file.txt.  While I'm not sure about iOS, this should work perfectly fine on OSX.

Comment: That gives me "Unable to redirect output: Bad file descriptor". Any ideas?

Comment: Separate out the two calls and see which one or if both calls fail.

Answer (score 7):

When you run the process redirect stderr to stdout like this:

```
myprocess 2>&1
```

Comment: Well I want to ship with that as my debug mode. I think there is no way to do that every time the app launches

Comment: If you want all output to go to `stdout`, then you could always stop writing to `stderr` and write to `stdout` instead.

Comment: Cocoa writes debug notes to stderr when my app crashes. Thats why I need that :P I tried writing everything to stderr too but that messes up the order too.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look at [Log4Cocoa](http://log4cocoa.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: It seems a little much to add another framework just to log some printfs. But I will have a look at it. Thanks